# Adding URL Params or bodies with any type of request

Tags: android-volley

It seems a tad cumbersome to add URL Params and also doesn't seem possible to add a body to any kind of request.

Sometimes, I need to add a body (like one would in a POST request) to DELETE, GET, PUT requests. As much as I really enjoy Volley, I feel like it isn't as loose as many would like. To adhere to it, the company has had to change some of the way our back-end is written.

Is there a nice and easy way to add a body to any type of method. Understandable, but upsetting if not.

Further, is there an easy way to add URL Params out of a HashMap or JSONObject?

Lately, I've found myself doing this:

```
StringBuilder buildUrl = new StringBuilder(BASE_URL);
buildUrl.append("items")
        .append("/")
        .append(item.getId())
        .append("/")
        .append("edit.json")
        .append("?")
        .append("user_id=")
        .append(params.optString("user_id"))
        .append("&")
        .append("auth_token")
        .append(params.optString("auth_token"));
```

and then using that String as the URL. Is there an easier way built into Volley? If not, I'll just cook up my own function for it.

Comment: For Volley's Delete Request, please go to my GitHub https://github.com/ngocchung/DeleteRequest

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add a body to your JSONObject requests.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html):

> JsonObjectRequest—A request for retrieving a JSONObject response body at a given URL, allowing for an optional JSONObject to be passed in as part of the request body.

I've only tried it with POST so can't comment on other HTTP methods - let me know what you find out. I do it like this:

```
JSONObject listItemData = new JSONObject();

    try {
        // Do what you're gonna do
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then pass it into your request like so:

```
JsonObjectRequest createItemRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, CreateItemUrl, listItemData,
                new Response.Listener....
  //.....
)
```